# Checking the consistency of a component

Tags: extensions, debug

As a Joomla newbie, it's quite hard to get started developing a component. At least, the Joomla 4 component isn't finished yet.

**Does a tool exist, which checks the consistency of a component? Reports e.g. bad naming or missing files?**

Actually, I use this material to get started:

- [Joomla 4.x Tutorial - Extension Development - The Way to Joomla 4 Extensions](https://blog.astrid-guenther.de/en/der-weg-zu-joomla4-erweiterungen/)
- [How to Create Joomla 4.x Component](https://www.techfry.com/resources/how-to-create-joomla-component)
- [Developing an MVC Component for Joomla 4.x](https://docs.joomla.org/J4.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/en)

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific tool or script that can check for missing files or directories in your component per se however using a decent IDE like PhpStorm has in built features that help you code. Then there are Joomla specific add-ons to the IDE's you can use that will help you follow Joomla conventions and there are more generalised coding tools like code sniffers that will help you write better code.

There are also a few Joomla specific things you can add to the IDE's to help warn you if you are using code that is depreciated or will be depreciated and that can help you write better Joomla code.

The approach Joomla has taken, which is what you will be exposed to in the tutorials you have listed, is to have you follow certain conventions and Joomla will 'automagically' or by default do obvious things for you. The obvious example of this is where if you call your controller class FredController, it will attempt to get a model called FredModel, a table class called FredTable, etc. This can get you going quicker with Joomla but can be hard to follow what is happening at times if you want to understand things better.

Once you get an understanding and experience from the basic tutorials of Joomla and then you start to move beyond the default conventions of Joomla I believe you will really start to see a lot more to Joomla than the basic single MVC convention the Tutorials describe.

> "bad naming or missing files?"

That is a bit ambiguous as a file/class could be reported as 'Missing' or 'Not Found' because it doesn't exist, in incorrectly named, does not have the right case in its name or it is correct but it hasn't been loaded properly.

A common issue you will find is developing locally on a Windows or Mac environment and things working fine only to fail when you move to the Linux based public server because you have not used the correct uppercase letter.

Two further references that I think will help you in developing for Joomla are

https://manual.joomla.org/
and
https://www.dionysopoulos.me/book.html

Comment: Thx! Unfortunately, for a newie error reports are sometime misleading. E.g. the latest message indicated a XXX layout missing. I fixed it using a layout name just like the View YYY. Quite likely, that's my fault. Still lead me in the wrong direction.

Comment: Adittionally, I added the backtrace to show parameters or at least class names in case of classes, to provide me more details what has been passed around. I wonder, why the default doesn't show these details.

Comment: Tanns for providing the link to https://www.dionysopoulos.me/book.html . The best stuff I found yet. Much better than the book and the eBook I bought.

Comment: A general hint for the incorrect/missing type errors is that if the file, or folder, contains a Class statement then the first character needs to be in Uppercase. If it is not a class, i.e. form, layout, tmpl, etc. then it will have a lowercase first letter.

Comment: Thx! I wonder, why importing an extension doesn't check such pitfalls and provides a hint.